# Solutions to systems of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Suppose I have two systems of equations $\bf{Ax}$=$\bf{b}$ and $\bf{Cy}=\bf{d}$ each with unique solutions. What are the necessary and/or sufficient conditions for the solutions to be identical ?

Comment: $x=y \implies A^{-1}b = C^{-1}d$

Comment: That is obvious. I meant conditions on $\bf{A}$, $\bf{C}$, $\bf{b}$ and $\bf{d}$.

Comment: Well that 'obvious' condition gives you a condition on A,C,b,d.

Comment: What more can you say ? For example, any relationship between $\bf{A}$ and $\bf{C}$ or between $\bf{b}$ and $\bf{d}$ ?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ need not be quadratic: consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}x=\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}x=\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\6\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need that $A$ and $C$ have the same numbers of column vectors.  If the solutions are unique the column vectors of the matrices are linearly independent, hence $A^tA$ and $C^tC$ are invertible.  From here
$$(A^tA)^{-1}A^tb=(C^tC)^{-1}C^td.$$

Comment: If $A$ and $C$ are square matrices, then the answer in the first comment (by Vizag) holds. Otherwise, if $A$ and $C$ are of full column rank, then the answer by Michael Hoppe holds. Finally, if $A$ and $C$ are of full row rank, then $x=y\Rightarrow A^{t}(AA^{t})^{-1}b=C^{t}(CC^{t})^{-1}d$.